# INVALID_URL deploying next.js app to Azure Static Webapp during github actions build

Tags: typescript, next.js, github-actions, azure-static-web-app

I am getting the error below, and spinning wheels figuring it out. It only happens during my github actions build. When I run the build locally, it works fine and I can hit the route handler. I can also run the github action locally using [act](https://github.com/nektos/act) and Docker, and then I get the error as well.

Here's the error:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at new URL (node:internal/url:676:13)
    at new ni (/home/runner/work/frontend/.next/server/app/api/reports/route.js:6:40210)
```

And the file in question is `src/app/api/reports/route.tsx`:

```
export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url);  // <- here is the problem
  const id = searchParams.get('id');
  const partitionKey = searchParams.get('partitionKey');

  if (!id || !partitionKey) {
    return NextResponse.json({msg: 'Success'});
  }
```

The result I expect is that the build completes and I can hit:
`http://localhost:3000/api/reports?id=SOME_ID&partitionKey=SOME_KEY`

And get a result. The actual result is the error above, during build time (not even runtime).

When I run it locally, the URL above works.

I have tried a ton, including:

1. I changed the name of the file to `route-bad.tsx` and the build succeeds
2. I took out the URL parsing and the build succeeds.
3. I tried an alternate form of build parsing the just uses strings and the `qs` library. I still get the error.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to proppelly include the url start different ways URL://www
Www.skaj.dom
HTTP://www etc.

Comment: You mean here: `new URL(request.url)`?
Something like: `new URL(\`https://${request.url}\`)` but with a variety of those options?

Comment: Only part after „new” in that case of your answer For Example instead of adding quotation etc.  Whole URL For http://www.Google.com instead URL. Change in new part whole hyperlink instead of in URl „URL:(www „ to www. You half way there i can see already ${req is good path

Comment: Baciscally you got an error “invalid url”

Comment: I appreciate the reply but I don't think it's the URL format at issue. This part works fine at runtime. I am figuring out why React is running this code at build time at all. This is where it breaks and something is not setup correctly. This article is giving me some good leads: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/35534

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. This discussion helped point me in the right direction: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/35534

Turns out this was just a red herring:

`const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url);  // <- here is the problem`

The real problem is here:

```
const cosmosClient = new CosmosClient({
  endpoint: COSMOS_ENDPOINT,
  key: COSMOS_KEY,
});
export async function GET(request: Request) {
  ...
}
```

Two issues were happening together:

1. I was creating the `CosmosClient` outside of the function call, meaning that importing this file caused that bit to be executed. That's why the error happened during the compile. I moved the initialization into the function.
2. It happened at all because in the github action, the environment variables were not set during the build. They were set later during the deploy. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76072684/345428) talks about the solution I used to set the environment variables during the build on the github action.

With those 2 fixed, the error goes away. A tricky one, but I definitely understand React compilation better.